# Merging cells in LaTeX tables

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a very simple table:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Implementation}         & Test 1  & Test2  &  Test3    \\\hline
                                        & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{results}   \\\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It works almost "perfect", the only problem that I have is that
the hline still goes through the first two cells that I have merged.
Basically, it looks like this

```
"-------------------------------------------------"
"|                | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 |"
" ----Implementation-------------------------------"
"|                |     results      |"  
"-------------------------------------------------"
```

However, it should like this:

```
"-------------------------------------------------" 
"|               | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 |"
"   Implementation    ---------------------------"
"|               |      results     |"   
"-------------------------------------------------"
```

Anyone an idea how to get rid of the line in the first column?

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

The command you want is \cline{i-j} which lets you draw a row divider across only certain columns.  See http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-214.html for details.

In particular, you'll want to use \cline{2-4} to draw a horizontal line across just the columns you mentioned.  Here's your code with the one change:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Implementation}         & Test 1  & Test2  &  Test3    \\\cline{2-4}
                                        & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{results}   \\\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to *not* address your question, I'll note that many authorities suggest minimizing the amount of internal ink in your table (i.e. ditch the `\hline`s between ordinary rows), and using something line [the last figure here](http://www.andy-roberts.net/misc/latex/latextutorial4.html).

If you are not constrained by some tightly defined style guide, this would be my solution.